# ArrayList to two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that has objects that are a latitude, and a longitude. I need to translate them to a two dimensional array.

```
public void DrawPolygon(ArrayList<PointModel> pModel){
    int size=pModel.size();
    double [][] latlon= new double[size][size];
    for(int i=0;i<pModel.size();i++){
        //What to do here, so I can get double[0][0][latitude of first index of arraylist][longitude of first index of array], and so on 
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the wrong size for the array,it need to be `double[size][2]` instead of `double[size][size]`

```
public void DrawPolygon(ArrayList<PointModel> pList){
    int size=pList.size();
    double [][] latlon= new double[size][2];
    for(int i=0;i<pList.size();i++){
         latlon[i][0] = pList.get(i).getLatitude();
         latlon[i][1] = pList.get(i).getlongitude();
    }
}
```

Also, make an `ArrayList` called `pModel` is a very bad idea.

Comment: Sure, I had to wait 10 minutes before I can vote, but I did not forgot about it.